# add a new column that the values will be a calculation from the same table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a new column to the table called a summary, that the values it gets will be  a calculation of column 1 - column 2 from the same table (summary),

This is the table:

**TABLE SUMMARY**

| id | target | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ******** | 10 | 14 |

Here's what I wrote -

```
ALTER TABLE Summary
ADD difference int;
Insert into (difference)
Value (SELECT target – Sales FROM Summary);
```

Is this a valid query, and if not, how to write it more correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Relational tables aren't spread sheets! Preferably don't add a column that depends on others at all. Or at least use a computed/generate column, if you DBMS, which you didn't disclose, supports them. Or create a view with the calculation.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The logic that you are trying to implement would seem to be `update`:

```
ALTER TABLE Summary ADD difference int;

UPDATE Summary
    SET difference = (target – Sales);
```

Note that this only works on the data already in the table.  The value of `difference` in new rows or in rows where the data changes is out-of-date -- unless you insert the correct values or do further updates.

Most databases support generated columns.  These are a great convenience -- and ensure that the value is always in synch when you query it.  Typical syntax is:

```
alter table summary add difference int generated always as
     (target - Sales);
```

As written, this value is calculated when the table is queried (which adds a very small overhead).  Most databases can also persist generated columns, so the database actually stores the value -- but also keeps it up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column to that table :

```
alter table summary add diff as  target – Sales
```

it will be calculated without effort.

note that this is calculated on the fly, IT HAS A COST ON EVERY EXECUTION

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: The cost is totally minimal and certainly is not worthy of all caps.